# Pandas df.values causes additional memory consumption

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a big pandas dataframe with about 300 columns and the column types are all float32. I would like to try machine learning algorithms with the data, so I call `df[x_columns].values` to create the numpy ndarray which will then be used as input to machine learning algorithms. By looking at memory consumption, it seems df[x_columns].values create a copy of the original data instead of just a view. Is it possible to only make it create a view of the original data so I can reduce the memory consumption?

Comment: You can always use **del df**  to delete its reference from the memory, don't know if that will help you. You can check it there : https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-clear-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python

Comment: what's the dtype of the values array?  When I've look at small frames with uniform column dtype, the values is a view.  But for this work the frame has to be storing the data in a single 2d array to begin with.

Comment: Did u try using df.to_numpy() instead?

Comment: @Odhian Yes I indeed deleted df but the memory consumption does not go down. In fact my experience is pandas rarely releases the memory just like a black hole, even if the dataframe is deleted or is created as a temporary variable in a function.

Comment: @Muhammadhassan Yes I tried it, and it behaves the same as df.values in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: @hpaulj the columns I pick are all float32 types, while there are indeed other columns with int32 and int64 types in the dataframe that I did not use when creating the numpy array.

Comment: Look at `df._mgr`.  I think it can return a `view` for each `block`.  I don't know if it can do so for a subset of  a block.  I have a pretty superficial knowledge of how `pandas` manages its data.

Comment: You may also want to try to open only chunks of your dataframe at a time, using **chunksize** parameter from **pandas.read_csv**. In other word, maybe you can train and get a decent result with less rows. You could also do *feature selection* to try to reduce the number of columns you are using.

Comment: I can confirm that `.values` indeed creates a copy, which is a huge pain. What worked for me as to avoid it entirely, either by continue working with DataFrames or bypassing pandas entirely. Would appreciate any updates on your findings.

Answer (score 0):

The first time, use this.

```
np_values = (df[x_columns].values).to_numpy
np.savez('values.npz', values=np_values) # saves a .npz file to disk
```

For all future runs with this program, comment out any lines dealing with your pandas df and directly read in from the saved numpy array.

```
# comment out [pandas df stuff]
values = np.load('values.npz')['values'] # reads the numpy file, np_values is now a numpy array
```

I'm unfamiliar with the pandas dataframe format, but you could save the whole dataframe and access them from the numpy array using np.savez and np.load somehow.